# Checkout Page in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, checkout, shopify-liquid

I am working with a Shopify plus account, I have the Payment Screen page (3 pages).
My problem is that I would like in the information screen under the contact section, to give the option to the user to choose the shipping method just like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2vSA.png)

But I don't know how to do it, I have read about, checkout.liquid but it will stop being active in August and also about Checkout Extensibility but I can't figure out how to do it, no matter how much I read documentation.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

looks like single page checkout you can enable it in shopify admin settings.
If you want to offer your customers shipping and local pickup like shown in the image you can do the following:
You can go to your shopify admin dashboard -> settings -> shipping and delivery -> local pickup

Comment: Hello, if you look closely, there are 3 pages, not just one, and I want to do it in three but hey, I'll find out how to do it. Thank you